# Currency Converter - removal of warnings

Tags: java

How could I improve my below program? I do have some warnings.

For example:

`toString() may produce a null pointer exception`. I tried to get around that, by specifying the `!=null` in the `if` statement `if (from != null && to != null && from.equals("NZD"))`, but that hasn't worked.

`Duplicate map key`

`if statement can be replaced with switch statement` - I tried this, but because my switch expression returned a boolean, it wasn't allowed.

Any constructive criticism gladly welcomed :) Thank you very much, in advance

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Converter {
    public void converterFrame() {
        String[] currenciesAvailableToExchange = {"NZD", "GBP", "AUD", "USD"};

        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();

        // INPUT AMOUNT
        JLabel inputHeading = new JLabel("How much would you like to convert?");
        inputHeading.setBounds(80, 20, 300, 20);

        JFormattedTextField input = new JFormattedTextField();
        input.setBounds(350, 20, 90, 20);

        // BUTTON
        JButton doneButton = new JButton("Done");
        doneButton.setBounds(250, 150, 90, 20);

        // HEADING
        JLabel fromHeading = new JLabel("FROM");
        fromHeading.setBounds(80, 20, 400, 100);

        // LIST OF CURRENCIES
        JComboBox<String> fromCurrency = new JComboBox<>(currenciesAvailableToExchange);
        fromCurrency.setBounds(80, 80, 140, 20);
        fromCurrency.setVisible(true);


        JLabel toHeading = new JLabel("TO");
        toHeading.setBounds(350, 20, 400, 100);


        // LIST OF CURRENCIES
        JComboBox<String> toCurrency = new JComboBox<>(currenciesAvailableToExchange);
        toCurrency.setBounds(350, 80, 140, 20);
        toCurrency.setVisible(true);

        // ADD ALL TO THE FRAME
        jFrame.add(input);
        jFrame.add(inputHeading);
        jFrame.add(fromHeading);
        jFrame.add(toHeading);
        jFrame.add(toCurrency);
        jFrame.add(fromCurrency);
        jFrame.add(doneButton);


        jFrame.setLayout(null);
        jFrame.setSize(700, 300);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);


        doneButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            String convertedResult = convertCurrencies(Double.parseDouble(input.getText()), fromCurrency, toCurrency);
            JTextField convertedResultTextField = new JTextField(convertedResult);
            convertedResultTextField.setVisible(true);
            convertedResultTextField.setBounds(250, 180, 240, 20);
            jFrame.add(convertedResultTextField);

            System.out.println(fromCurrency);
            System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(input.getText()));
        });


        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public String convertCurrencies(Double conversionAmount, JComboBox<String> fromCurrency, JComboBox<String> toCurrency) {
        String from = fromCurrency.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String to = toCurrency.getSelectedItem().toString();

        double result = 0.0;

        if (from !=null && to != null && from.equals("NZD")) {

           if (to.equals("GBP")) {

            } else if (to.equals("AUD")) {
                result = convertToAUD(toCurrency, conversionAmount);
            } else if (to.equals("USD")) {
                result = convertToUSD(toCurrency, conversionAmount);
            } else {
                System.err.println("Something went wrong with the conversion");
            }
        }
        if (from != null && to != null && from.equals("GBP")) {
            if (to.equals("NZD")) {
                result = convertToNZD(toCurrency, conversionAmount);
            } else if (to.equals("AUD")) {
                result = convertToAUD(toCurrency, conversionAmount);
            } else if (to.equals("USD")) {
                result = convertToUSD(toCurrency, conversionAmount);
            } else {
                System.err.println("Something went wrong with the conversion");
            }
        }

        if (from != null && to != null && from.equals("AUD")) {
            if (to.equals("NZD")) {
                result = convertToNZD(toCurrency, conversionAmount);
            } else if (to.equals("GBP")) {
                result = convertToGBP(toCurrency, conversionAmount);
            } else if (to.equals("USD")) {
                result = convertToUSD(toCurrency, conversionAmount);
            } else {
                System.err.println("Something went wrong with the conversion");
            }
        }

        if (from != null && to != null && from.equals("USD")) {
            if (to.equals("NZD")) {
                result = convertToNZD(toCurrency, conversionAmount);
            } else if (to.equals("GBP")) {
                result = convertToGBP(toCurrency, conversionAmount);
            } else if (to.equals("AUD")) {
                result = convertToAUD(toCurrency, conversionAmount);
            } else {
                System.err.println("Something went wrong with the conversion");
            }
        }

        return ("Your converted currency is " + result);

    }

    public double convertToNZD(JComboBox<String> toCurrency, double conversionAmount) {
        String to = toCurrency.getSelectedItem().toString();

        Hashtable<String, Double> nzRates = new Hashtable<>();
        nzRates.put(to, 1.0);
        nzRates.put(to, 2.0);
        nzRates.put(to, 3.0);

        double rate = nzRates.get(to);
        return rate * conversionAmount;

    }

    public double convertToGBP(JComboBox<String> toCurrency, double conversionAmount) {
        String to = toCurrency.getSelectedItem().toString();

        Hashtable<String, Double> ukRates = new Hashtable<>();
        ukRates.put(to, 4.0);
        ukRates.put(to, 5.0);
        ukRates.put(to, 6.0);

        System.out.println(to);
        double rate = ukRates.get(to);
        return rate * conversionAmount;

    }

    public double convertToAUD(JComboBox<String> toCurrency, double conversionAmount) {
        String to = toCurrency.getSelectedItem().toString();

        Hashtable<String, Double> auRates = new Hashtable<>();
        auRates.put(to, 7.0);
        auRates.put(to, 8.0);
        auRates.put(to, 9.0);

        double rate = auRates.get(to);
        return rate * conversionAmount;

    }

    public double convertToUSD(JComboBox<String> toCurrency, double conversionAmount) {
        String to = toCurrency.getSelectedItem().toString();

        Hashtable<String, Double> usRates = new Hashtable<>();
        usRates.put(to, 10.0);
        usRates.put(to, 11.0);
        usRates.put(to, 12.0);

        double rate = usRates.get(to);
        return rate * conversionAmount;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Converter converter = new Converter();
        converter.converterFrame();
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. I don't see `switch` statement in your code. 2. `toString` doesn't, and cannot, know that you've sanitized your input. You have to qualify every method calling `toString` with `throws NullPointerException`, and catch it somewhere.

Comment: Warnings aside, do the results you get when running your code match what you expect?

Comment: Are you're sure your `JComboBox` has a selected item at the beginning ? If not this would explain the warning about the null pointer exception.

Comment: @SaraJ, yes they do :)

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  But I'm sorry; this code can't work.  All the `convertTo` methods are implemented incorrectly.  The duplicate key is part of that.  (Hint:  you should be passing constants not `to`, e.g. `nzRates.put("GBP", 1.0);`.)  Once you get it working, there is plenty to critique about the code, but you have to get it working first to get that criticism.  The "if statement can be replaced with switch statement" is on-topic here but the "Duplicate map key" is not.  The "toString() may produce a null pointer exception" is borderline.